# moving a product from default category to correct category

Tags: category, default

If a product is incorrectly assigned to a category - in my case, to the default, how does one change the product to the correct category? I want to move a product that is now in "default" to "earrings"

Comment: Don't you mean `Attribute Set` instead of `Category`?

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Click on the Default Category and click on the Category Product tab.under it uncheck the check box of the product which you want to remove from the Default category and click save product.

2) Click on the Earring Category and click on the Category Product tab.under it click on the reset button and check the checkbox of that product and click on the save product.
```

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** Assuming that you mean that the product is incorrectly assigned to an
>   `Attribute Set` instead of a `Category`.

Changing the Attribute Set of a product in Magento from one Attribute Set to another Attribute Set is not possible out of the box. You would need to make quite a few changes to the database (manually) which is very risky. So I don't recommend doing this.

What I can recommend is using the **Flagbit Change Attribute Set** extension for this purpose. I have this extension installed in my own store and it works flawlessly. It is free and you can download it from [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html).

As always, make sure that you have a good backup of your Magento file system and database before installing the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  `catalog-> Manage products`click on the edit to product you want `change->categories->uncheck` the `current assigned categories` and `check` the `new categories` in which you want to assign the product.   Hope this will help!!!